# how to extract the borders of an image (OCT/retinal scan image)

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an (OCT) image like shown below (original). As you can see, it mainly has 2 layers. I want to produce an image (shown in the 3rd picture), in which the red line indicates the top border of 1st layer, the green shows the brightest part of the 2nd layer.

[image: original]

[image: pic with borders]

[image: red line:top border of first layer, green line: brightest line in the 2nd layer]

I have tried to simply thresholded the image. Then I can find the edges like shown in the 2nd image. But how can produce the red/green lines from these borders?

PS: I am using matlab (or OpenCV). But any ideas with any languages/psudo codes are welcomed. thanks in advance

Comment: What language(s) are you using? Please add the appropriate language tags to allow more people to help you.

Comment: I added the information to the original post. Any languages/ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not have too much time for this right now but you can start with this:

1. **blur the image a bit (remove noise)**

   simple convolution will do for example few times with matrix

   ```
   0.0 0.1 0.0
   0.1 0.6 0.1
   0.0 0.1 0.0
   ```
2. **do color derivation by y axis**

   derivate pixel color along `y` axis... for example I used this for each pixel of input image:

   ```
   pixel(x,y)=pixel(x,y)-pixel(x,y-1)
   ```

   beware the result is signed so you can normalize by some bias or use `abs` value or handle as signed values ... In my example I used bias so the gray area is zero derivation ... black is most negative and white is most positive
3. **blur the image a bit (remove noise)**
4. **enhance dynamic range**

   Simply find in image the min color `c0` and max color `c1` and rescale all pixels to predefined range `<low,high>`. This will make the tresholding much more stable across different images...

   ```
   pixel(x,y)=low + ((pixel(x,y)-c0)*(high-low)/(c1-c0)
   ```

   so for example you can use `low=0` and `high=255`
5. **treshold all pixels which are bigger then treshold**

The resulting image is like this:

[image: preview]

Now just:

1. **segment the red areas**
2. **remove too small areas**
3. **shrink/recolor areas to leave just the midpoint on each `x` coordinate**

   The top most point is red and the bottom is green.

This should lead you to very close state to your wanted solution. Beware blurring and derivation can move the detected positions a bit from their real position.

Also for more ideas take a look at related **QA**s:

- [How to find horizon line efficiently in a high-altitude photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22195176/2521214)
- [Fracture detection in hand using image proccessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046721/2521214)

**[Edit1] C++ code of mine for this**

```
picture pic0,pic1,pic2;     // pic0 is your input image, pic1,pic2 are output images
int x,y;
int tr0=Form1->sb_treshold0->Position;  // treshold from scrollbar (=100)
// [prepare image]
pic1=pic0;                  // copy input image pic0 to output pic1 (upper)
pic1.pixel_format(_pf_s);   // convert to grayscale intensity <0,765> (handle as signed numbers)
pic2=pic0;                  // copy input image pic0 to output pic2 (lower)

pic1.smooth(5);             // blur 5 times
pic1.derivey();             // derive colros by y
pic1.smooth(5);             // blur 5 times
pic1.enhance_range();       // maximize range

for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)     // loop all pixels
 for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
  if (pic1.p[y][x].i>=tr0)  // if treshold in pic1 condition met
   pic2.p[y][x].dd=0x00FF0000; //0x00RRGGBB then recolor pixel in pic2

pic1.pixel_format(_pf_rgba); // convert the derivation signed grayscale to RGBA (as biased grayscale)

// just render actual set treshold
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Font->Color=clYellow;
pic2.bmp->Canvas->TextOutA(5,5,AnsiString().sprintf("Treshold: %i",tr0));
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
```

The code is using Borlands **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** bitmap/canvas  at bottom (not important for you just renders actual treshold settings) and my own `picture` class so some members description is in order:

- `xs,ys` resolution
- `color p[ys][xs]` direct pixel access (32bit pixel format so 8 bit per channel)
- `pf` actual selected pixel format for the image see the `enum` bellow
- `enc_color/dec_color` just pack unpack color channels to separate array for easy multi pixel format handling ... so I do not need to write each function for each pixelformat separately
- `clear(DWORD c)` fills image with color `c`

The `color` is just `union` of `DWORD dd` and `BYTE db[4]` and `int i` for simple channel access and or signed values handling.

Some chunks of code from it:

```
union color
    {
    DWORD dd; WORD dw[2]; byte db[4];
    int i; short int ii[2];
    color(){}; color(color& a){ *this=a; }; ~color(){}; color* operator = (const color *a) { dd=a->dd; return this; }; /*color* operator = (const color &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
enum _pixel_format_enum
    {
    _pf_none=0, // undefined
    _pf_rgba,   // 32 bit RGBA
    _pf_s,      // 32 bit signed int
    _pf_u,      // 32 bit unsigned int
    _pf_ss,     // 2x16 bit signed int
    _pf_uu,     // 2x16 bit unsigned int
    _pixel_format_enum_end
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void dec_color(int *p,color &c,int _pf)
    {
    p[0]=0;
    p[1]=0;
    p[2]=0;
    p[3]=0;
         if (_pf==_pf_rgba) // 32 bit RGBA
         {
         p[0]=c.db[0];
         p[1]=c.db[1];
         p[2]=c.db[2];
         p[3]=c.db[3];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_s   ) // 32 bit signed int
         {
         p[0]=c.i;
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_u   ) // 32 bit unsigned int
         {
         p[0]=c.dd;
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_ss  ) // 2x16 bit signed int
         {
         p[0]=c.ii[0];
         p[1]=c.ii[1];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_uu  ) // 2x16 bit unsigned int
         {
         p[0]=c.dw[0];
         p[1]=c.dw[1];
         }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void dec_color(double *p,color &c,int _pf)
    {
    p[0]=0.0;
    p[1]=0.0;
    p[2]=0.0;
    p[3]=0.0;
         if (_pf==_pf_rgba) // 32 bit RGBA
         {
         p[0]=c.db[0];
         p[1]=c.db[1];
         p[2]=c.db[2];
         p[3]=c.db[3];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_s   ) // 32 bit signed int
         {
         p[0]=c.i;
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_u   ) // 32 bit unsigned int
         {
         p[0]=c.dd;
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_ss  ) // 2x16 bit signed int
         {
         p[0]=c.ii[0];
         p[1]=c.ii[1];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_uu  ) // 2x16 bit unsigned int
         {
         p[0]=c.dw[0];
         p[1]=c.dw[1];
         }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void enc_color(int *p,color &c,int _pf)
    {
    c.dd=0;
         if (_pf==_pf_rgba) // 32 bit RGBA
         {
         c.db[0]=p[0];
         c.db[1]=p[1];
         c.db[2]=p[2];
         c.db[3]=p[3];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_s   ) // 32 bit signed int
         {
         c.i=p[0];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_u   ) // 32 bit unsigned int
         {
         c.dd=p[0];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_ss  ) // 2x16 bit signed int
         {
         c.ii[0]=p[0];
         c.ii[1]=p[1];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_uu  ) // 2x16 bit unsigned int
         {
         c.dw[0]=p[0];
         c.dw[1]=p[1];
         }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void enc_color(double *p,color &c,int _pf)
    {
    c.dd=0;
         if (_pf==_pf_rgba) // 32 bit RGBA
         {
         c.db[0]=p[0];
         c.db[1]=p[1];
         c.db[2]=p[2];
         c.db[3]=p[3];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_s   ) // 32 bit signed int
         {
         c.i=p[0];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_u   ) // 32 bit unsigned int
         {
         c.dd=p[0];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_ss  ) // 2x16 bit signed int
         {
         c.ii[0]=p[0];
         c.ii[1]=p[1];
         }
    else if (_pf==_pf_uu  ) // 2x16 bit unsigned int
         {
         c.dw[0]=p[0];
         c.dw[1]=p[1];
         }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void picture::smooth(int n)
    {
    color   *q0,*q1;
    int     x,y,i,c0[4],c1[4],c2[4];
    bool _signed;
    if ((xs<2)||(ys<2)) return;
    for (;n>0;n--)
        {
        #define loop_beg for (y=0;y<ys-1;y++){ q0=p[y]; q1=p[y+1]; for (x=0;x<xs-1;x++) { dec_color(c0,q0[x],pf); dec_color(c1,q0[x+1],pf); dec_color(c2,q1[x],pf);
        #define loop_end enc_color(c0,q0[x  ],pf); }}
        if (pf==_pf_rgba) loop_beg for (i=0;i<4;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])>>2; clamp_u8(c0[i]);  } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_s   ) loop_beg                   { c0[0]=(c0[0]+c0[0]+c1[0]+c2[0])/ 4; clamp_s32(c0[0]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_u   ) loop_beg                   { c0[0]=(c0[0]+c0[0]+c1[0]+c2[0])>>2; clamp_u32(c0[0]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_ss  ) loop_beg for (i=0;i<2;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])/ 4; clamp_s16(c0[i]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_uu  ) loop_beg for (i=0;i<2;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])>>2; clamp_u16(c0[i]); } loop_end
        #undef loop_beg
        #define loop_beg for (y=ys-1;y>0;y--){ q0=p[y]; q1=p[y-1]; for (x=xs-1;x>0;x--) { dec_color(c0,q0[x],pf); dec_color(c1,q0[x-1],pf); dec_color(c2,q1[x],pf);
        if (pf==_pf_rgba) loop_beg for (i=0;i<4;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])>>2; clamp_u8(c0[i]);  } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_s   ) loop_beg                   { c0[0]=(c0[0]+c0[0]+c1[0]+c2[0])/ 4; clamp_s32(c0[0]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_u   ) loop_beg                   { c0[0]=(c0[0]+c0[0]+c1[0]+c2[0])>>2; clamp_u32(c0[0]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_ss  ) loop_beg for (i=0;i<2;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])/ 4; clamp_s16(c0[i]); } loop_end
        if (pf==_pf_uu  ) loop_beg for (i=0;i<2;i++) { c0[i]=(c0[i]+c0[i]+c1[i]+c2[i])>>2; clamp_u16(c0[i]); } loop_end
        #undef loop_beg
        #undef loop_end
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void picture::enhance_range()
    {
    int i,x,y,a0[4],min[4],max,n,c0,c1,q,c;
    if (xs<1) return;
    if (ys<1) return;

    n=0;    // dimensions to interpolate
    if (pf==_pf_s   ) { n=1; c0=0; c1=127*3; }
    if (pf==_pf_u   ) { n=1; c0=0; c1=255*3; }
    if (pf==_pf_ss  ) { n=2; c0=0; c1=32767; }
    if (pf==_pf_uu  ) { n=2; c0=0; c1=65535; }
    if (pf==_pf_rgba) { n=4; c0=0; c1=  255; }

    // find min,max
    dec_color(a0,p[0][0],pf);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) min[i]=a0[i]; max=0;
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        dec_color(a0,p[y][x],pf);
        for (q=0,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            c=a0[i]; if (c<0) c=-c;
            if (min[i]>c) min[i]=c;
            if (max<c) max=c;
            }
        }
    // change dynamic range to max
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        dec_color(a0,p[y][x],pf);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) a0[i]=c0+(((a0[i]-min[i])*(c1-c0))/(max-min[i]+1));
//      for (i=0;i<n;i++) if (a0[i]<c0) a0[i]=c0; // clamp if needed
//      for (i=0;i<n;i++) if (a0[i]>c1) a0[i]=c1; // clamp if needed
        enc_color(a0,p[y][x],pf);
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void picture::derivey()
    {
    int i,x,y,a0[4],a1[4];
    if (ys<2) return;
    for (y=0;y<ys-1;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        dec_color(a0,p[y  ][x],pf);
        dec_color(a1,p[y+1][x],pf);
        for (i=0;i<4;i++) a0[i]=a1[i]-a0[i];
        enc_color(a0,p[y][x],pf);
        }
    for (x=0;x<xs;x++) p[ys-1][x]=p[ys-2][x];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know its quite a bit of code ... and the equations are all you need but you wanted this :) on your own. Hope I did not forget to copy something.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Also very happy you did actually continue making the effort of limiting your bullet-points! :D +1 for ya!

Comment: @AnderBiguri heh still few couple hundreds answers remains bulleted ... :)

Comment: @Spektre Could you help to explain (if possible some code) how to do color derivation by y axis? Do I do the derivatives along the y axis? So something like this (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)? Sorry about the stupid question

Comment: @wildcolor yes you derivate `pixel color` along `y` axis... for example I used this for each pixel of input image:  `pixel(x,y)=pixel(x,y)-pixel(x,y-1)` beware the result is signed so you can normalize by some bias ... or use `ab`s value, or handle as signed values ... In my example I used bias so the gray area is zero derivation ... black is most negative and white is most positive

Comment: @Spektre thanks for your reply. Is there any chance to post your example code here, as I am also not very sure about how to implement 'Enhance dynamic range'...

Comment: @wildcolor added more info if you really need code I got it in C++ but I think equations are better for grasping this then code (as I do not use Matlab nor OpenCV)... if you need it anyway comment me and I will add it.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks a million for adding the equation. They are really really helpful. But if it is possible, could you please add the c++ code? It will be extremely useful to me. Could you also section the codes according to your step labels?

Comment: @wildcolor you got it in `[edit1]` the main code is first and straight forward and the subroutines are at the end of edit ... they a bit confusing from start but its what I used... (the code evolved to its current state for a reason)

Comment: @Spektre Many thanks for your detailed answers. I am still trying to transfer/implement your solution with my own code. I have come to step 5.  Then I noticed after step 5, you have another 3 steps (1. segment; 2 remove too small areas; 3. shrink ...) Are these steps meant to be below step 5 (ie: 1 becomes step 6; 2 becomes 7 etc)? Also, how can I implement 'remove too small areas', this seems to be a bit difficult?

Comment: @wildcolor yes those 3 steps are just additional post processing to improve results (if needed) as I did not know what precision/quality of input/output you got and need. Removing of too small areas is easy. Just count the pixels (by floodfill recolor or whatever else) for each red region and according to size (count of pixels, bounding box aspect ratio or whatever else) either leave it as result or remove by recolor to black color or whatever ...

Comment: there is also bluring based method ... create mask of all red points (max intensity) and the rest is black (similar to ROI) now blur the mask few times (the more the bigger regions will be removed) now treshold the mask against some value or leave just max intensity pixels. Now compare original mask and blured and remove regions where no set pixels is left.

Answer (score 3):

The following set of instructions (using Matlab Image processing toolbox) seems to work well for your image:

1. Blur your image (Im) with a median filter to decrease the noise:

   ```
   ImB=medfilt2(Im,[20 20]);
   ```
2. Find the edges using sobel mask and dilate them a little bit to connect close components, and 'clean' the overall image to get rid of small areas

   ```
   edges = edge(ImB,'sobel');    
   se = strel('disk',1);
   EnhancedEdges = imdilate(edges, se);    
   EdgeClean = bwareaopen(EnhancedEdges,1e3);
   ```

   [image: EdgeClean.png]
3. You then have your two zones, that you can detect separately using bwlabel

   ```
   L=bwlabel(EdgeClean);
   ```
4. Finally, plot the two zones corresponding to L=1 and L=2

   ```
   [x1 y1] = find(L==1);
   [x2 y2] = find(L==2);
   plot(y1,x1,'g',y2,x2,'r')
   ```

   [image: ImZones.png]

There are not a lot of steps because your initial image is quite nice except from the noise. You may need to play a bit on the parameters as I started from a downloaded version of your image which can be of lesser quality than the original one. Of course this is a minimal code, but I still hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fantastic answers from 'Spektre' and 'Dpeurich'. Both of them are really help. I am new to image processing. Thanks for attaching the code Dpeurich. I tried it on my other images. It seems to be working

Comment: @wildcolor if this answers works for you you should accept it as a solution to your problem (the checker near Votes count). Also the author of this answer is `Toghe` not `Dpeurich` or am I missing some deleted comments?

Comment: Spektre Thanks for the advice. I apologise for using the wrong name,  @Toghe. Not sure why I typed in that name.

Comment: Actually I changed my name after your first comment @wildcolor so you did not do any mistake :), my apologies

Answer (score 2):

A full working implementation in Octave:

```
pkg load image
pkg load signal

median_filter_size = 10;
min_vertical_distance_between_layers = 35;
min_bright_level = 100/255;

img_rgb = imread("oct.png");% it's https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBnOj.png
img = im2double(img_rgb(:,:,1));
img=medfilt2(img,[median_filter_size median_filter_size]);

function idx = find_max(img,col_idx,min_vertical_distance_between_layers,min_bright_level)
  c1=img(:,col_idx);

  [pks idx]=findpeaks(c1,"MinPeakDistance",min_vertical_distance_between_layers,"MinPeakHeight",min_bright_level);

  if ( rows(idx) < 2 )
    idx=[1;1];
    return
  endif

  % sort decreasing peak value
  A=[pks idx];
  A=sortrows(A,-1);

  % keep the two biggest peaks
  pks=A(1:2,1);
  idx=A(1:2,2);

  % sort by row index
  A=[pks idx];
  A=sortrows(A,2);

  pks=A(1:2,1);
  idx=A(1:2,2);
endfunction

layers=[];
idxs=1:1:columns(img);
for col_idx=idxs
  layers=[layers find_max(img,col_idx,min_vertical_distance_between_layers,min_bright_level)];
endfor
hold on
imshow(img)
plot(idxs,layers(1,:),'r.')
plot(idxs,layers(2,:),'g.')

my_range=1:columns(idxs);

for i = my_range
  x = idxs(i);
  y1 = layers(1,i);
  y2 = layers(2,i);
  if  y1 > rows(img_rgb) || y2 > rows(img_rgb) || x > columns(img_rgb) || y1==1 || y2==1
    continue
  endif
  img_rgb(y1,x,:) = [255 0 0];
  img_rgb(y2,x,:) = [0 255 0];
endfor 

imwrite(img_rgb,"dst.png")
```

The idea is to process every column of the image as a curve (of grey levels) and looking for two peaks, each peak is on the border of a layer.

The input image is the original linked by the OP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBnOj.png [image]

The image saved by the code as `"dst.png"` is the following:

[image]