# How to project IR image on a 2D plane using OpenCV and PCL

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a **Kinect** and I'm using **OpenCV** and point cloud library. I would like to project the **IR** Image onto a **2D** plane for forklift pallet detection. How would I do that?

I'm trying to detect the pallet in the forklift here is an image:

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "project the IR Image onto a 2D plane"? which plane? Is the image you've given as example the one you want to project?

Comment: @Raluca yes the image that's in the example I want to project it, including the point cloud

Comment: @Raluca If I have the IR image and point cloud from depth map, how would I recognize the pallet ?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. You want to project that image onto a plane? If so, which plane? or you want to project the point cloud onto that image?

Comment: yes I want to project the point cloud onto that image

Comment: If your goal is to detect the pallet, why don't you use machine learning? OpenCV has such algorithms. You would need a database with images with and without a pallet, labelled accordingly.

Comment: do you have the point cloud as an image or as a set of 3D data?

Comment: can you guide me to opencv maching learning algorithms ? 
I have a point cloud converted to a height map and I have the point cloud as a set of 3D Data

Comment: is there an easier way instead of machine learning. I'm a beginner and I dont have much experience with opencv

Comment: I can see you are a beginner in image processing/OpenCV and you're trying to resolve a complex problem. Who's asking you that? Is it a school project?

Comment: Regarding the machine learning techniques: it's been a while since I last used one and OpenCV evolved since. You could take a look at their documentation. I think they should have some sample code. I guess SVM could work for you http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/ded/group__ml.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Regarding you question if there is an easier way: it is still not clear to me what's your goal. Just to detect the presence of the pallet in an image? You want to segment/locate it in the image? would it always be a forklift there? What's the context of all of this?

Comment: yes I want to segmnet and locate it in the image. yes there will be always a fork lift, and I have the point cloud from two depth camera and I also have the point cloud converted to height map for blob selection.

Comment: how SVM would work in my case ? I have seen that post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images, but I don't know what should I do, I'm a beginner and have no clue. Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115347/discussion-between-andre-and-raluca).

Comment: @andre added few idies as an answer. You should add the RGB and Depth image data (Your image is neither) + FOV of your Kinect cameras in case anyone would like to give it a shot....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the **RGB** data? You can use it to help with the detection. You do not need to project the image onto any plane to detect a pellet. There are basically 2 ways used for detection

1. **non-deterministic based on neural network, fuzzy logic, machine learning, etc**

   This approach need a training dataset to recognize the object. Much experience is needed for proper training set and classifier architecture/topology selection. But other then that you do not need to program it... as usually some readily available lib/tool is used just configure and pass the data.
2. **deterministic based on distance or correlation coefficients**

   I would start with detecting specific features like:

   - **pallet has specific size**
   - pallet has sharp edges and **specific geometry** shape in depth data
   - pallet has **specific range of colors** (yellowish wood +/- lighting and dirt)
   - Wood has specific texture patterns

   So compute some coefficient for each feature how close the object is to real pallet. And then just treshold the distance of all coefficients combined (possibly weighted as some features are more robust).

I do not use the **#1** approach so I would go for **#2**. So combine the **RGB** and depth data (they have to be matched exactly). Then segmentate the image (based on depth and color). After that for each found object classify if it is pallet ...

**[Edit1]**

Your colored image does not correspond to depth data. The aligned gray-scale has poor quality and the depth data image is also very poor. Is the depth data processed somehow (loosing precision)? If you look at your data from different sides:

[image]

You can see how poor it is so I doubt you can use depth data for detection at all...

PS. I used my [Align already captured rgb and depth images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35914008/2521214) for the visualization.

The only thing left is the colored image and detect areas with matching color only. Then detect the features and classify. The color of your pallet in the image is almost white. Here HSV reduced colors to basic 16 colors (too lazy to segmentate)

[image: color reduction]

You should obtain range of colors of the pallets possible by your setup to ease up the detection. Then check those objects for the features like size, shape,area,circumference...

**[Edit2]**

**So I would start with Image preprocessing:**

1. **convert to HSV**
2. **treshold only pixels close to pallet color**

   I chose `(H=40,S=18,V>100)` as a pallet color. My HSV  ranges are `<0,255>` per channel so `Hue` angle difference can be only `<-180deg,+180deg>` max which corresponds to `<-128,+128>` in my ranges.
3. **remove too thin areas**

   Just scan all Horizontal an Vertical lines count consequent set pixels and if too small size recolor them to black...

This is the result:

[image: example1]

On the left the original image (downsized so it fits to this page), In the middle is the color treshold result and last is the filtering out of small areas. You can play with tresholds and pallet color to change behavior to suite your needs.

Here **C++** code:

```
int tr_d=10;    // min size of pallet [pixels[
int h,s,v,x,y,xx;
color c;

pic1=pic0;
pic1.pf=_pf_rgba;
pic2.resize(pic1.xs*3,pic1.ys); xx=0;
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Draw(xx,0,pic0.bmp); xx+=pic1.xs;

// [color selection]
for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
    {
    // get color from image
    c=pic0.p[y][x];
    rgb2hsv(c);
    // distance to white-yellowish color in HSV (H=40,S=18,V>100)
    h=c.db[picture::_h]-40;
    s=c.db[picture::_s]-18;
    v=c.db[picture::_v];
    // hue is cyclic angular so use only shorter angle
    if (h<-128) h+=256;
    if (h>+128) h-=256;
    // abs value
    if (h<   0) h=-h;
    if (s<   0) s=-s;
    // treshold close colors
    c.dd=0;
    if (h<25)
     if (s<25)
      if (v>100)
       c.dd=0x00FFFFFF;
    pic1.p[y][x]=c;
    }
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Draw(xx,0,pic1.bmp); xx+=pic1.xs;

// [remove too thin areas]
for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;y++)
 for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;)
    {
    for (   ;x<pic1.xs;x++) if ( pic1.p[y][x].dd) break;    // find set pixel
    for (h=x;x<pic1.xs;x++) if (!pic1.p[y][x].dd) break;    // find unset pixel
    if (x-h<tr_d) for (;h<x;h++) pic1.p[y][h].dd=0;         // if too small size recolor to zero
    }
for (x=0;x<pic1.xs;x++)
 for (y=0;y<pic1.ys;)
    {
    for (   ;y<pic1.ys;y++) if ( pic1.p[y][x].dd) break;    // find set pixel
    for (h=y;y<pic1.ys;y++) if (!pic1.p[y][x].dd) break;    // find unset pixel
    if (y-h<tr_d) for (;h<y;h++) pic1.p[h][x].dd=0;         // if too small size recolor to zero
    }
pic2.bmp->Canvas->Draw(xx,0,pic1.bmp); xx+=pic1.xs;
```

See [how to extract the borders of an image (OCT/retinal scan image)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37963338/2521214) for the description of `picture` and `color`.  Or look at any of my **DIP/CV** tagged answers. Now the code is well commented and straightforward but just need to add:

You can ignore `pic2` stuff it is just the image posted above so I do not need to manually print screen and merge the subresult in paint...  To improve robustness you should add enhancing of dynamic range (so the tresholds have the same conditions for any input images). Also you should compare to more then just single color (if more wood types of pallet is present).

**Now you should segmentate or label the areas**

1. **loop through entire image**
2. **find first pixel set with the pallet color**
3. **flood fill the area with some distinct ID color different from set pallet color**

   I use black `0x00000000` space and white `0x00FFFFFF` as pallete pixel color. So use `ID={1,2,3,4,5...}`. Also remember number of filled pixels (that is your area) so you do not need to compute it again. You can also compute bounding box directly while filling.
4. **compute and compare features**

   You need to experiment with more then one image. To find out what properties are good for detection. I would go for circumference length vs area ratio. and or bounding box size... The circumference can be extracted by simply selecting all pixels with proper ID color neighboring black pixel.

See also similar [Fracture detection in hand using image proccessing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046721/2521214)

Good luck and have fun ...

Comment: I have added the RGB image and Depth Image. Can you please write a pseudo code or opencv code of approach 2, to help me more. I have no idea how to do it properly.

Comment: please I need help :)

Comment: @andre addded edit ... need help with what exactly (I do not use OpenCV so no I can not write the code in it)

Comment: so you converted the image to HSV ? and then what should I do next ? how would I detect the size, shape, area ? should I use findcontours to extract the pallet ?

Comment: can you segmentate it and show an example please ? even in pseudo code to implement the algorithm my self