# How to find height of the specific point in this OCT image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical

I am a beginner in Matlab who is working on medical image processing of retinal OCT images. My aim is to align all the images to 1 height value. I want to find the maximum height of the layer in the eye.

For example, if input :
[image: Original image]

the output: returns this height:

[image: Height]
I have tried this approach as outlined in [Hand_height](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48244-object-height-and-width-measure?s_tid=prof_contriblnk) but it returns the height of the complete image.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over X and find the first peak (blue point) using `findpeaks` in the vertical direction (Y) to generate the first layer (blue line),
and then determine the peak with the smallest index in the Y-direction.
[Please see the image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkSNf.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to find maximum high you should find the top border of a retina.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942697/how-to-extract-the-borders-of-an-image-oct-retinal-scan-image) you have an example of how to find it.